# Regular Expression Java non alpha numeric character matching

Tags: java, regex

I want to match an expression like this:

`500 q 6h`

Where the numbers can be any integer (thus `2 q 500h` is also a legal expression).

I'm trying to match this pattern using the following regular expression
 `(\W|^)\d+ q \d+h(\W|$)`

Using this pattern, I would expect a string like

`a500 q 6h`  to be not matched. Instead it is matched.

Similarly, I would expect a string like

`(500 q 6h)` to be matched,  but it is not matched.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: ^[0-9]+ q [0-9]+h$ should work

Comment: Is the expression in your question directly copied and pasted from your code? I ask because `\W\$` is almost certainly incorrect, and there's likely a `+` missing after the second `\d` also. Be sure that your `\W` are actually uppercase.

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson That wouldn't match `(500 q 6h)` though.

Comment: ^\\(?[0-9]+ q [0-9]+h\\)?$ revised to match (500 q 6h)

Comment: @CorvinMcpherson I think the questioner wants something to match any reasonable delimiter, not just brackets. And try using backticks to quote literal code.

Comment: @Elliott: show your relevant code ;)

Comment: @BraddSzonye I see what your saying, would ^[\W]*\d+ q \d+h[\W]*$ work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(?<!\w)\d+ q \d+h(?!\w)
```

For example: http://www.rubular.com/r/IY6T8GvK7D

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note double backslashes required by java in String literals)

```
\\b\\d+ q \\d+h
```

I've used the "word boundary" regex `\b` to handle the "preceding letter" issue.